# How to query firebase database to return a value's key's parent's parent?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a team chat application . I am storing chat data in firebase.

This is my Data structure [image]

- The chats are stored under a node named `chats`.
- each immediate child of `chats` is the name of a team(like whatsapp.. chat groups).
- the `team` node have all chat messages. the chat messages are stored
- with a parent node in the format `timestamp_chat`

**My Problem**

Now I have to create a firebase query to fetch this team nodes by from key.

That is 
if a `from:` field contains the a given search value (say, "ragesh"), then the parent node "team_name" have to be returned(say,"teamrova") as a datasnapshot.

Simply speaking , I want datasnapshot of teams that have a particular username in the `from` field.

**My Work**

I tried the follwing code :

```
  reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");

    Query chatQuery = reference1.orderByChild("from").equalTo("ragesh");
    System.out.println("Chat list :: starting");

    chatQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            System.out.println("Chat list :: onChildAdded");

            for (DataSnapshot chat : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                System.out.println("Chat list :: The chat group is =>" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                System.out.println("Chat list :: The key & Value => " + chat.getKey() +" :: "+chat.getValue().toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ChatListActivity.this, "Connection Error "+databaseError.getDetails(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Chat list :: databaseError "+databaseError.toString());


        }
    });
```

> Sadly , above code don't return any value. even the
>   `System.out.println("Chat list :: onChildAdded");` not called. And it
>   doesn't calls onCancelled also.(so,no error).

I get sturcked by this. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

To get the username:

```
mRootRef.child("chats").child("teamrova").orderByChild("from").equalTo("ragesh").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String name=datas.child("from").getValue().toString();



}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

Since you are using `addChildeventListener` then you do not need the for loop to be able to get those values `for (DataSnapshot chat : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {`

You also need to change this:

```
 reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
```

to this:

```
reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child("teamrova");
```

The above code is an alternative with `addValueEventListener`

Comment: Since the use case here is Search so its better to use SingleValueEvent to get data only once and avoid changes in search result.

Comment: But if I do'nt know the team name ?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I want to retrieve the team name , so I can't hardcode the `teamrova` in the program.

Comment: @LordCommander okay if the snapshot is on `chats` and you do not know the team names, then you need to iterate twice but orderbychild(..) wont work. Since orderbychild is ordering the children that are under the direct child

Comment: @PeterHaddad ... Will you please give code for this?.. please .. I am new to firebase.